# Bessel identities

Tags: bessel-potential

Please help me prove the following identity
$$
a(J_1(a)Y_0(a)-J_0(a)Y_1(a))=\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
for any $a$.
$J$ and $Y$ are bessel functions of the first and second kind respectively.

Thank you.

Comment: what is "*" in your notation? Too much MATLAB recently ? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to computing the Wronskian of $J_0$ and $Y_0$, since $J'_0 = -J_1$ and $Y'_0 = -Y_1$.
$$
W(x) =
\begin{vmatrix}
J_0 & Y_0 \\\
J'_0 & Y'_0
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
J_0 & Y_0 \\\
-J_1 & -Y_1
\end{vmatrix} =
J_1 Y_0 - J_0 Y_1.
$$
But the zeroth-order Bessel equation is:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0.
$$
By Abel's formula, $W(a) = \frac{W(1)}{a}$. You now have to compute any value of $W$.

Comment: $$W(a)=W(1)e^{-\int_1^a\frac{1}{x}dx}=\frac{W(1)}{a}$$

Comment: Thank you.<br>
The proof is almost complete now it is required to prove that:
$$
(J_1(1)Y_0(1)-J_0(1)Y_1(1))=\frac{2}{\pi}
$$

Comment: You must have finished this by now I am sure, but just in case, to conclude, once you know it is constant, you just have to compute the limit as a->0, very easy with the explicit formulae.